# Select all records after the CHAR c

Tags: mysql, sql, char

I have a column(char) with values between A and Z
I only want to select the records where the char is >= 'C'

Can anyone help me with this?
I tried >= 'C' but this didn't work. Also I couldn't find anything about this on the internet. So I thought it's a good question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ascii`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii) value for comparison.

```
select * from tablename where ascii(colname) >= ascii('C')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is the the only way to do it? Or do you know a different solution as well? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: i wonder why `col >= 'C'` didn't work for you. that is one more way.

Answer (score 0):

here is another method.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(YourColumn,'c',-1) FROM Yourtable;
```

Comment: Isn't SUBSTRING intended to use only for multiple characters?

Comment: it can be used to get the string after a particular character. see [link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be compared in MySQL with regular comparison operators, so this should work:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col >= 'C'`

Do note that the exact sort order (mainly case sensitivity) for strings depends on your characterset collation. Maybe that is the reason why it didn't work for you.

You can also use `ASCII()` function, which returns the character value of a single character, and compare those:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(col) >= ASCII('C')`

Note that this only works for single byte characters. For multi byte characters you must use `ORD()` instead of `ASCII()`.

Yet another way is to use `STRCMP()` which compares two strings (again, using the sort order of your characterset collation) and returns 0 if the strings are the same, -1 if the first argument is smaller than the second, and 1 otherwise.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE STRCMP(col, 'C') >= 0`